# counter help - Pure PHP - self created pagination

Tags: php

The code I have works absolutely perfectly:

```
<?
$maxresults = 10;
$total = $row[total];  
$pagecount = $total / $maxresults; 
 if (!isset($_GET['page'])) { $_GET['page'] = '1'; } 
$startcount = (($_GET['page'] - 1) * $maxresults + 1); 
$stopcount = $startcount + ($maxresults - 1);
$lastTime = null;
$i='0';
$sc = $startcount; 
$stmt=$db->prepare("// SELECT STATEMENT");
 $stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
 $stmt->execute();

     while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        if (!($sc > $stopcount)) {
            $i++;
            if( $row['time'] !== $lastTime ) { 
                if ( $lastTime === NULL ) {
                   echo '// close of loop'; 
                } else { 
                   echo '// loop grouping as title'; 
                }
                $lastTime = $row['time'];
            } 

            if ($i >= $sc) { ?>
               // the html to loop
            <?   
               $sc++;
            }  
        }
    }
?>
```

Forward and Back buttons are easy enough to create. if $_GET['page'] * 10 > $total, active the next button, if $_GET['page'] > 1 activate previous button.

What I can't figure out is the correct formula and loop so I can always display the correct number of "page numbered" links. I want to always show 5 based on the 3rd number. So 1 would should 5 links: 1 - 5, 2 would also show 1 - 5, as would 3, 4 would show 2 - 6, 5 would show 3 - 7.

Now obviously, I could just add 2 and subtract 2 from the current $_GET[page] if the get page is greater than 3, but I need to take into account testing to see if the results go that high. So only if results are greater than 10 should number 2 show, and then if on page 16 pages 17 and 18 should only show if there are 170 and 180 results to display.

Perhaps I have just been staring at the code to long, but I can't seem to get a formula or loop correct in my head to even attempt the code page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a fairly specific question. Wasn't sure if anyone would help with something so specific or not. Guess I learned.

Here is the answer to my own question:

```
<ul>
    <li class="<? if ($_GET['page'] < '2') { echo 'disabled' ; } ?>">
        <a href="<? 
                   if ($_GET['page'] == '2') { 
                       echo 'inbox.php'; 
                   } else { 
                       echo '?page='.($_GET[page] - 1); 
                   } 
                 ?>">Prev</a>
    </li> <!-- previous button-->

    <li style="<? if ($_GET['page'] - 2 < '1') { echo 'display:none;'; } ?>">
        <a href="?page=<? 
                         echo ($_GET[page] -2); ?>">
                         <? echo ($_GET[page] -2); ?>
        </a>
    </li> <!-- the button 2 before current spot if its greater than 0 -->

    <li style="<? if ($_GET['page'] - 1 < '1') { echo 'display:none;'; } ?>">
        <a href="?page=<? 
                         echo ($_GET[page] -1); ?>">
                         <? echo ($_GET[page] -1); ?>
        </a>
    </li> <!-- the button 1 before current spot if its greater than 0 -->

    <li class="disabled">
        <a href=""><? echo $_GET[page]; ?></a>
    </li> <!-- current button disabled -->

    <li style="<? if ($total - ($_GET[page] * 10) <= '0') { echo 'display:none;'; } ?>">
        <a href="?page=<? 
                         echo ($_GET[page] + 1); ?>">
                         <? echo ($_GET[page] +1); ?>
        </a>
    </li> <!-- the button 1 after current spot if results go that high -->

    <li style="<? if ($total - ($_GET[page] + 1) * 10 <= '0') { echo 'display:none;'; } ?>">
        <a href="?page=<?
                          echo ($_GET[page] + 2); ?>">
                          <? echo ($_GET[page] + 2); ?>
        </a>
    </li> <!-- the button 2 after current spot if results go that high -->

    <li class="<? if ($total - ($_GET[page] * 10) <= '0') { echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="?page=<? echo ($_GET[page] + 1); ?>">Next</a>
    </li> <!-- the next button if results go that high -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad to see you found your own solution there Bruce.

Answer (score 0):

@bruce after seeing your solution, I'd like to give you my own solution.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$max_pages = ceil($total / $maxresults);
$min_pages = 1;

$start = max($min_pages, $page-2);
$end = min($max_pages, $start+2);

$nav = ($page > $min_pages ? '<li><a href="?page=' . $page-1 . '">&lt;</a></li>' : '' );
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++)
    $nav .= '<li' . ($i == $page ? 'class="active"' : '' ) . '><a href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
$nav .= ($page < $max_pages ? '<li><a href="?page=' . $page+1 . '">&gt;</a></li>' : '' );
```